# Kotlin Multiplatform: no such table problem

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am following [main documentation](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/multiplatform_sqlite/) to integrate SQL Delight in KMM project.

I added

```
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("MyDatabase") {
            packageName.set("com.example.db")
        }
    }
}
```

And in commonMain/com/example/db there is:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position TEXT NOT NULL
);

insert:
INSERT INTO User (name, position) VALUES (?, ?);

-- Select Query
select:
SELECT * FROM User;

delete:

DELETE FROM User;
```

To use it I created in commonMain:

```
class PersistenceRep(factory: DriverFactory) {
val driver = factory.createDriver()
val database = MyDatabase(driver)
val queries = database.newUserQueries

@Throws(Exception::class)
suspend fun getSomething(): List<User> {
    return queries.select().executeAsList()
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
suspend fun delete() {
    return queries.delete()
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
suspend fun insert() {
    return queries.insert("name", "position")
}
}
```

I assembled XCFramework of project and when I want to call any function from class above, I am getting

```
error while compiling: INSERT INTO User (name, position) VALUES (?, ?)
no such table: User | error code SQLITE_ERROR
co.touchlab.sqliter.interop.SQLiteExceptionErrorCode: error while compiling: INSERT INTO User (name, position) VALUES (?, ?)
no such table: User
```

I also cleaned and rebuilded projec and run generateSqlDelightInterface

What am I doing wrong if I am following official docs?

Comment: It's a runtime error saying the table doesn't exist, which means the table hasn't been created (most likely). Please post the code that creates the driver on native.